# Looking to add a cewp to bottom of welcome page that shows pictures from library - jquery

Tags: jquery

I have been asked to set up a SP site at work. I have site collection priv. with no access to SP designer. I have looked around on the internets for a way to make a cewp that would display 4 or 5 images from our image library on the bottom of our default page. How would I do this? Also, it has been asked that they not be 'hard coded' urls, that it could be any 5 of the increasingly growing number of images in the library. Can anyone point me somewhere to begin this process?

I have an image rotator that uses jquery, and it works great, so I figured it would have to be along that line... or at least that's what I've been searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default home page is designed with a big hardcoded content editor web part inside it - it allows you to add rich content to it in the page edit mode. So you can simply add your HTML code inside it - there's an option in the Ribbon to edit CEWP content HTML:
[image]

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, but unfortunately, I have no access to SP Designer. I have to do this all from scratch in a content editor webpart.

Comment: It's all in the browser only - no need in SPD.